# How do I localize js templates in Django

Tags: django, internationalization, localization

I've the problem, template for dynamic JS file is main.js located in TEMPLATE_DIRS. When I do ./manage.py makemessages -a all messages {% trans "MSG" %} are fetched but not from main.js template.
Of course I can rename main.js to main.js.html, is any pretty way?
./manage.py  makemessages -d djangojs — dont help.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify extensions in `makemessages` command (see [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#message-files)):

```
django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l de -e js -e html,txt
```